# Determining all endpoints (vertices) on set of linear constraints

Tags: geometry, analysis, functions, analytic-geometry

I would like to know how to determine all endpoints or intersections (vertices) of multidimenzional planes.

Let's say I have an object (for example multidimensional cube) given by the following sets of inequalities ($p$-times *leq*; $q$ times *geq*):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1,1} & \dots & a_{1,i} & \dots  & a_{1,n} \\
    a_{2,1} & \dots & a_{2,i} & \dots  & a_{2,n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{p,1} & \dots & a_{p,i} & \dots  & a_{p,n}
\end{bmatrix} 
*
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{i} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{n} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\leq
\begin{bmatrix}
    H_{1} \\
    H_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    H_{p} 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    b_{1,1} & \dots & b_{1,i} & \dots  & b_{1,n} \\
    b_{2,1} & \dots & b_{2,i} & \dots  & b_{2,n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    b_{q,1} & \dots & b_{q,i} & \dots  & b_{q,n}
\end{bmatrix} 
*
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{i} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{n} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\geq
\begin{bmatrix}
    L_{1} \\
    L_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    L_{q} 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Where $\boldsymbol{x}$ are variables, $\boldsymbol{a} $, $\boldsymbol{b} $, $\boldsymbol{L} $, and $\boldsymbol{H}$ are parameters: $\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{b}, \boldsymbol{L}, \boldsymbol{H} \in \mathbb{R}$.

In other words I have some angular object, for example as provided in this [illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWR2f.png), and would like to find all the endpoints. I am more interested in those violet ones, because considering additional constraints for nonnegativity, the object would be compact.

What I thought of yet is to use some modification of simplex algorithm. However, I am not sure how to modify it such that it identifies all the endpoints. Also, I am inquiring if there is something a little bit better and easier to implement.

Thank you very much.